# "Колотня спорола". Прошу объяснить, что произошло

Tags: значения

Я отдал маленький подарок для знакомой девушки её брату.

Он мне потом СМС-сообщил: "Эта колотня сразу всё спорола".
Что это может значить?

Comment: что за подарок?

Comment: may be just a typo - школотня

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подарок был вкусный.
Мой знакомый из Москвы. Сейчас он пояснил:

колотня = колотушка = бестолковая

спорола = съела

Это нормально?

Comment: Боюсь, ни в одном словаре не нашлось бы подобного толкования слова `колотня`. А вот насчет `спорола`, я все же угадал. :)

Comment: "Спороть" в значении "съесть" часто употребляется в сельской местности, обычно по отношению к домашним животным. Например: "Я вчера кучу рыбы наловил, а кошка ночью ее всю спорола".

Comment: Странно, я сам из Москвы (причем у меня несколько поколений предков отсюда и некоторые особенности именно московского говора я за собой знаю), но данная фраза мне совершенно не понятна (вариант "примерно догадался о чем речь" не берем).

Answer (score 4):

Если подарок съедобный, то `спорола` вполне может означать `съела`.
Насчет `колотня`. Полагаю, речь тут идет о значении этого слова "убой на мясо". В данном контексте - персона, отъедающаяся на убой.
Таким образом, исходная фраза означает примерно:

```
Это ненасытная сразу съела ваш подарок.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш знакомый из Украины?
В Украине "колотня" - разговорное название ссоры, драки. "Спорола" - наверняка синоним запорола, т.е. *испортила*.

В общем и целом скорее всего зависит от контекста: того что это был за подарок, обстоятельств в которых его передавали  и т.п.